# C# obtain existing Form1 instance from static method in Form1

Tags: c#, oop, instance, static-methods

I know its very easy question, but nobody can give simple answer.

Obtain existing Form1 instance from static method in Form1

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        callMethod();           
    }

    public static void callMethod()
    {
       // how can get existing Form1 instance here ?             
       statusLabel.Text = "test";
    }
}
```

Please, it isn't important why I need this, but important to know how.

Comment: what's the statuslabel? is it static?

Comment: @Sangram, no its not static.

Comment: @Sever What's the purpose of this? This seems awfully wrong, really!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do it like this though i'd still suggest seperating or creating a model for the values you need and pass it around. See the message concept of .net

```
public static Form1 Instance
{
   get
   {
      return instance;
   }
}
```

and add this to your constructor

```
    private static Form1 instance;
    public Form1()
    {
        instance = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Comment: "this" is not valid in a static property

Comment: @Sever "this" does not apply to a static object, but to "Form1" which has only "public" as modifier. Thus, it is legitimate. It is the variable "instance" that is declared static, which is not the same.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword '`this`' returns a reference to the current instance of the class containing it.

Static methods (or any static member) do not belong to a particular instance. They exist without creating an instance of the class.

You cannot really access any member unless you make them static. In your case assuming `statusLabel` is textbox, it won't allow you to access it insider a static method.

either make your function non static or you can use something like following code.

```
callMethod(statusLabel);  

public static void callMethod(Label txt)
 {

    txt.Text = "test";
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can pass Form1 as parameter to callMethod

```
public static void callMethod(Form form1)
{

   form1.doSomething(); //use Form1 instance
   statusLabel.Text = "test";

}
```

and you can pass Form1 instance to it. For example, you can call it below if called from within Form1 e.g: on one of it's member function :

```
Form1.callMethod(this);
```

however if you want to call it somewhere where you don't hold instance of Form1 thus cannot pass it as argument, you can try to use Singleton pattern instead, so you can code it is a below :

```
public static void callMethod()
{

   Form1.instance().doSomething(); //use Form1 instance
   statusLabel.Text = "test";

}
```

Comment: How can I call Form1.callMethod(this) from static method ? "this" not valid in a static property.

Comment: You call it like that if you call it within Form1 instance e.g: on one of its member function (not static). I didn't know previously you mean to call Form1.callMethod() from another static method. I've edited to add alternative to use Singleton pattern when you don't have access to instance directly.

Comment: thank you but Singelton would check for an existing instance, and if one is not present, the class would be instantiated, and to use  existing instance I need use "this", but as I described in previous comment "this" not valid in a static property

Comment: Yes, I never meant `this` to be used as static property. It's a keyword that refer to the current instance, so it has valid value if you use it within an **instance** e.g: within member (non-static) function. Like I said, previously I thought you will be calling it within Form1 instance. I should clarify it first.